# GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found

Tags: centos, glibc

My issue is:

Failed (/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by plugins)

I have installed g++ (GCC) 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10)
and centos version 6.10 (64 bit)

Comment: What generated that message?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it was generated when I try to run an application but one of the plugin on that application need this.

Comment: i have also insalled gcc and g++ of version 4.9.1 using devtoolset-3

Answer (score 1):

This means you downloaded an RPM or pre-compiled binary that is using a newer version of the main C/C++ libraries on your machine. **These cannot be changed.** You need to (a) find an RPM version specifically built for your version of CentOS (or earlier), (b) recompile the source code or RPMs on your machine, or (c) use a container (like Docker/Moby) and run it inside an image that has the newer libraries.